# (K)Ubuntu 23.10 Login Issue

Tags: kubuntu, login, wine

Yesterday, I tried to install a Windows-based game on Kubuntu 23.10. I attempted installation multiple times using both Wine and Winetricks. Unfortunately, I couldn't succeed in the installation, and it seems I may have somehow damaged the file system. Now, when Kubuntu boots, I encounter a black screen and a keyboard. Closing the keyboard opens a screen slightly similar to my login screen, with tabs labeled 'Session' and 'Layout' at the top. I can't make any changes in these tabs. On the top right of the screen, there are 'Restart' and 'Power off' buttons, which work, but restarting brings me back to this screen. On the left side, there's the date and time, working correctly. On the right, there's my photo and a box to enter my password. Initially, I could type using the keyboard I saw, and I can still enter text into this box on this screen. However, after entering the password, there's no 'login' button, and the 'enter' key doesn't work. I have tried 'Alt+Ctrl+F2,' but it didn't help. In summary, I can't progress beyond this screen.

Please help,
Kind Regards